# Why can't terminal alkynes take part in Birch reduction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, hydrocarbons, organic-reduction

According to my book terminal alkynes are not observed in Birch reduction.Why is this so? The only property I know about them is that they are slightly acidic. Does this have something to do with it? Please help me understand this.

Comment: As Waylander has already mentioned, acetylide formation occurs instead: [the introduction of this article clearly states this](https://www.doi.org/10.1021/jo01224a001). @Hema
Anyway, I am looking for a textbook with the mention that terminal alkynes are not suited for Birch reduction; would you mind telling me the name of the book you were looking at?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The alkyne proton is acidic enough to react with the dissolving metal to give the anion, giving the metal alkynide as it shown by these procedures [sodium acetylide prep](http://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV3P0416),  [sodium phenylacetylide prep](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo01101a604?journalCode=joceah); this does not reduce.